# python 3 code quality testing - improper function usage detection

Tags: python, unit-testing, automated-tests, enumerate

Is there a way to automatically (script) test if someone implemented a function with something that they were not allowed to use or if they used something stupid...

Example A -- check values of a with `range(len())`:

> Bad: `idx in range(len(a))` followed by `a[idx]`
>   Ok: `i, v in enumerate(a)`

Example B -- use `int()` when you are not allowed:

> Bad: `int('1')`
>   Ok: `a = ord('1')-ord('0')`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the keyword "assert" to avoid a certain behaviour, or even if you expected a different value. Actually your question is not that clear. Another idea would be try/except statment.

Comment: I've reworded my question. Thank you.